# How to save lines to a rich text format file (.rtf) in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

*Please note that this is a high school level application.

It's a lot easier to load the Tstings of a richedit into a textfile using the savetofile procedure rather than line by line, but that requires the use of a .rtf file.
The following code successfully creates the rtf file, funcQuestionID is a custom function which simply generates a string to name the file.

```
var
  sQuestionID, sLine: string;
begin
  sQuestionID := funcCreateQuestionID(frmLogin.sCurrentUser);
  FileCreate(sQuestionID + '.rtf');
end;
```

However when the savetofile procedure is added, the following error occurs:

"Cannot create file . The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

```
 sQuestionID := funcCreateQuestionID(frmLogin.sCurrentUser);
 FileCreate(sQuestionID + '.rtf');
 redOut.Lines.SaveToFile(sQuestionID + '.rtf');
```

The program seems to create the file and keep it in memory. How would one go about saving the lines?

Comment: Remove the call to `FileCreate`

Comment: Or add a call to `FileClose()` after `FileCreate()`.  You are leaking the file handle that `FileCreate()` returns, which is why the file is still "in use" when you try to save over it.

Comment: Neither call to `FileCreate` is needed. `SaveToFile` creates the file automatically, and closes it once the file is saved.